# NamedPipeClientStream throws UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, window, named-pipes

I have reviewed lots of similar questions but none seems to cover this case. So please check the details before assuming it is a duplicate.

Scenario:
I have a client and server application written in c# targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2 that communicates using NamedPipeClientStream and NamedPipeServerStream respectively.

The server is running as the local administrator account and creates the NamedPipeServerStream like this:

```
PipeSecurity ps = new PipeSecurity();
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
ps.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544"), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
NamedPipeServerStream mypipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("mypipe", PipeDirection.Out, 1, 0, PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 0, 0, ps);
mypipe.WaitForConnection();
```

On the server I have created a local account called "testuser" that is a member of the local administrators group. This account is used for authentication on the client when connecting to the Named Pipes over the network.

The client program is running as a local user on a different machine connected via network and creates the connection like this:

```
NamedPipeClientStream mypipe = new NamedPipeClientStream("<ip of server>", "mypipe", PipeDirection.In, PipeOptions.None);
mypipe.Connect();
```

When running the server software on Windows Server 2012 this works fine. But on Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2019 I get the UnauthorizedAccessException. If instead of my local user "testuser" I authenticate with the built-in Administrator account over the network, it works fine on all three version of windows server.

If I change the pipe security to use a SID of for example S-1-5-11 to allow "authenticated users" it also works on all three versions but the requirement is to only allow members of the local administrators group from connecting to the server over the network. Ideally it should not matter if the account is a local or domain account, but I have only tested with local accounts.

I have done some debugging using Event Viewer on the server and I can see Event 5145 (Detailed File Share) with Audit success for my testuser when accessing the pipe, but the client still reports UnauthorizedAccessException.

Is there any way to restrict access for only members of the local administrators group on windows server 2016 and 2019?

Comment: How does `testuser` on the client have anything to do with `testuser` on the server? That would only work if they both had the same password, and NTLM was used (local account, non-domain authentication). And why wouldn't you just use a proper domain account for this?

Comment: @Charlieface testuser only exists on the server as a local account. When running the code on the client, I have to authenticate against the server to open a connection to the SMB share "IPC$" for access to named pipe. So a dialog box is opened on the client to enter network credentials and there I supply either the local administrator account for the server, or my testuser credentials.

I want my program to be flexible to work in scenarios where I only have access to credentials for a local account. The important thing is that the account (local or domain) should be a local administrator

Comment: When entering credentials for a local user of the remote machine, you must enter it `RemoteMachineName\Username`. A domain user would be much easier, as both would recognize it automatically. You can add a domain user to the Local Administrators on the server.

Comment: Please do not focus on the domain user part. I do not think it is relevant for the problem and I know I can supply `RemoteMachineName` but it is not strictly required with for instance `.\Username`. Windows handles it for me. And as I said, the logs in the Event Viewer confirm that I authenticate correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else runs into this problem I found the cause.
The problem was "UAC remote restrictions". More information can be found in Microsoft's KB 951016

If a local account is a member of the `Builtin\Administrators` group and authenticates over the network for instance to an SMB share such as `\\remotecomputer\C$` or a named pipe, the account will not authenticate as a "full" administrator and thus not have access to administrative resources. Such accounts will have to be elevated from a interactive logon such as RDP to gain full administrative privileges. As such, my scenario with builtin accounts does not work because of this security feature.

There seems to be three ways to handle this problem.

1. Disable this security measure in the registry (probably not recommended).
2. Use a domain account and add that as a local administrator. This security restriction appears to only affect `SAM` (local) accounts.
3. Only use the builtin Administrator account as this is also not affected by the security restriction.

**Note** that if the registry is edited incorrectly there might be serious consequences. So backup the registry before performing any changes. The following instructions are based on Microsoft's article on the subject:

To disable the restriction in the registry:

1. Open the registry using `regedit` and select the following key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
2. Create the following key (type DWORD) if it does not exist, otherwise just edit it to have a value of 1: `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`.

Comment: Got this error using a Forms application to test named pipes message to a monitor in a windows service.  Running the Forms app as administrator solved the problem.